# Drupal 8 Custom Module - From dynamic data (API) to store at Fields (Content type) Drupal DB

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I've created a custom module in Drupal 8 that grab some data from an API, and puts them in the Drupal DB creating a new table.
I want to add this data as the contents of a specific content type.

How can I do that?

here is my code :

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_cron().
 */
function ods_cron() {
  $message = 'Cron run: ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

  $ods  = \Drupal::service('ods.ods');
  $conf = \Drupal::service('ods.ods_configuration_request');

  if ($conf->isDevelopment()) {
    // Development
    $response_bond = beforeSendRequest($conf->devUrlExternalBond(), 'GET');
    $response_mf = beforeSendRequest($conf->devUrlExternalMutualFund(), 'GET');
  } else {
    // Production
    $parameters_bond = [
      'headers' => $conf->headers(),
      'authorization' => $conf->basicAuthorization(),
      'data_post' => $conf->bodyBond(),
    ];
    $parameters_mf = [
      'headers' => $conf->headers(),
      'authorization' => $conf->basicAuthorization(),
      'data_post' => $conf->bodyMutualFund(),
    ];
    $response_bond = beforeSendRequest($conf->urlExternalBond(), 'POST', $parameters_bond);
    $response_mf = beforeSendRequest($conf->urlExternalMutualFund(), 'POST', $parameters_mf);
  }

  $raw_result_bond = json_decode($response_bond);
  $raw_result_mf = json_decode($response_mf);

  // Development
  if ($conf->isDevelopment()) {
    $raw_result_bond = json_decode($raw_result_bond[0]->field_bonds);
    $raw_result_mf = json_decode($raw_result_mf[0]->field_api);
  }

  $BondsProductList = $raw_result_bond->BondsProductInqRs->BondsProductList;
  $MFProductInqList = $raw_result_mf->MFProductInqRs->MFProductInqList;

  // Bond data store to internal
  if ($BondsProductList !==  null) {
    $bond_datas = [];
    foreach ($BondsProductList as $row => $content) {
      $bond_datas[] = [
        'AskPrice' => number_format($content->AskPrice, 1, '.', ','),
        'BidPrice' => number_format($content->BidPrice, 1, '.', ','),
        'BuySettle' => number_format($content->BuySettle, 1, '.', ','),
        'CouponFreqCode' => $content->CouponFreqCode,
        'CouponFreqID' => number_format($content->CouponFreqID),
        'CouponRate' => number_format($content->CouponRate, 2, '.', ','),
        'IDCurrency' => $content->IDCurrency,
        'LastCoupon' => $content->LastCoupon,
        'MaturityDate' => $content->MaturityDate,
        'MinimumBuyUnit' => number_format($content->MinimumBuyUnit),
        'MultipleOfUnit' => number_format($content->MultipleOfUnit),
        'NextCoupon' => $content->NextCoupon,
        'Penerbit' => $content->Penerbit,
        'ProductCode' => $content->ProductCode,
        'ProductName' => $content->ProductName,
        'ProductAlias' => $content->ProductAlias,
        'RiskProfile' => $content->RiskProfile,
        'SellSettle' => $content->SellSettle
      ];
    }

    $insert_data = $ods->setData(
      'bond',
      [
        'AskPrice', 'BidPrice', 'BuySettle', 'CouponFreqCode', 'CouponFreqID', 'CouponRate', 'IDCurrency',
        'LastCoupon', 'MaturityDate', 'MinimumBuyUnit', 'MultipleOfUnit', 'NextCoupon', 'Penerbit',
        'ProductCode', 'ProductName', 'ProductAlias', 'RiskProfile', 'SellSettle'
      ],
      $bond_datas
    );

    if ($insert_data) {
      // make response as JSON File and store the file
      $ods->makeJsonFile($bond_datas, 'feeds/bonds', 'bond.json');
    }

  }

  // Mutual Fund data store to internal
  if ($MFProductInqList !==  null) {
    $mf_datas = [];
    foreach ($MFProductInqList as $row => $content) {
      $mf_datas[] = [
        'ProductCode' => $content->ProductCode,
        'ProductName' => $content->ProductName,
        'ProductCategory' => $content->ProductCategory,
        'ProductType' => $content->ProductType,
        'Currency' => $content->Currency,
        'Performance1' => $content->field_1_tahun_mf,
        'Performance2' => $content->Performance2,
        'Performance3' => $content->Performance3,
        'Performance4' => $content->Performance4,
        'Performance5' => $content->Performance5,
        'UrlProspektus' => $content->UrlProspektus,
        'UrlFactSheet' => $content->UrlFactSheet,
        'UrlProductFeatureDocument' => $content->UrlProductFeatureDocument,
        'RiskProfile' => $content->RiskProfile,
        'FundHouseName' => $content->FundHouseName,
        'NAVDate' => $content->NAVDate,
        'NAVValue' => $content->NAVValue
      ];
    }

    $insert_data_mf = $ods->setData(
      'mutual_fund',
      [
        'ProductCode', 'ProductName', 'ProductCategory', 'ProductType', 'Currency', 'Performance1', 'Performance2', 'Performance3',
        'Performance4', 'Performance5', 'UrlProspektus', 'UrlFactSheet', 'UrlProductFeatureDocument', 'RiskProfile', 'FundHouseName',
        'NAVDate', 'NAVValue'
      ],
      $mf_datas
    );

    if ($insert_data_mf) {
      // make response as JSON File and store the file
      $ods->makeJsonFile($mf_datas, 'feeds/mf', 'mutual_fund.json');
    }

  }

  // console log
  \Drupal::logger('ods')->notice($message);
}
```

So can I store the data to pristine drupal 8 table?

Comment: With this sentence: I want to put that data to Drupal field (at Content Type) and put that data to Drupal pristine table. Do you mean that you want to add this datas as contents of a specific content type?

Comment: Yess @DavideCasiraghi. can I do that?

Comment: Have you already created the already the content type from the Drupal backend?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create the content type in the Drupal 8 backend going to Structure > Content type.

Second you can add a node programmatically like this

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

$node = Node::create(array(
    'type' => 'your_content_type',
    'title' => 'your title',
    'langcode' => 'en',
    'uid' => '1',
    'status' => 1,
    'body'=> 'your body',
));

$node->save();
```